# how can I show car's details When click on their names

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am making a website with node.js and I am new ,I want to learn a method if there is.I list cars using `ul` and  when I click on a car name i want to show car's details. How can I do it.

> html

```
<template name="vehicles">
<section id="vehicles" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-offset="200">Vehicle Models - <span class="subtitle">Our rental fleet at a glance</span></h2>
        </div>

        <!-- Vehicle nav start -->
        <div class="col-md-3 vehicle-nav-row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-offset="100">
            <div id="vehicle-nav-container">
                <ul class="vehicle-nav">
                    {{#each showcarnames}}
                    <li class="active"><a href="#vehicle-1">{{aracmarka}}</a><span class="active">&nbsp;</span></li>
                 {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="vehicle-nav-control">
                <a class="vehicle-nav-scroll" data-direction="up" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                <a class="vehicle-nav-scroll" data-direction="down" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Vehicle nav end -->

        <!-- Vehicle 1 data start -->
        <div class="vehicle-data" id="vehicle-1">
            <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="100">
                <div class="vehicle-img">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/vehicle1.jpg" alt="Vehicle">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-offset="200">
                <div class="vehicle-price">$ 37.40 <span class="info">rent per day</span></div>
                <table class="table vehicle-features">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Marka</td>
                        <td>{{carmark}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Model</td>
                        <td>{{carmodel}}</td>
                    </tr>



                </table>
                <a href="#teaser" class="reserve-button scroll-to"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Reserve now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> js

```
 Template.vehicles.helpers({
    showcarnames: function() {
      return cars.find();
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this problem using [Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session). You could target the data using a click event:

```
Template.vehicles.events({
    'click .vehicle-nav li': function(){
        Session.set('selected-vehicle', this._id); // or however you id the docs in your app.
     }
});
```

then create an event helper that gets the selected doc and returns it to the template.

```
Template.vehicles.helpers({
        getSelectedVehicle: function() {
            var selectedId = Session.get('selected-vehicle');
            return cars.findOne(selectedId);
        },
});
```

Session is a great and simple tool to manage user state, like what vehicle they have selected.

Finally, you would then need to get the values in your template somewhere

```
<!-- html-->
{{#if getSelectedVehicle}}
    {{#with getSelectedVehicle}}
      <!-- mark up, when using with you can access doc atts directly. -->
    {{/with}}
{{else}}
    <!-- tell the user to make a selection -->
{{/if}}
```

using [with](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_with) in this context can lead to more readable markup. But there are other ways to achieve the same result.

To recap, at a high level, You are targeting the users interactions with the UI, to set a global variable as a way to simplify managing state. Be sure to check out `Session` in the meteor docs, its very simple and powerful. (the above code is not tested, but hopefully conveys the idea)